# Non market apk update installer

Tags: android, apk, adb

I am newbie to Android development.I have a existing non-market android project.Now I want to create a update apk with new changes to code,assets etc.Below is my requirement.

when i install a new  updated apk ,i want all the existing configurations/data files to be deleted and fresh copy of apk to be installed.its like a uninstall followed by install. **adb install -r** doesn't work in my case as this retains the configurations/data files.Is there any option where in I can achieve the above mentioned expected apk behavior.what all the elements should i change in AndroidManifest.xml. As this is kind of update apk ,i cannot change the package name.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do adb install without the -r.  It will delete all files.  You could also explicitly do adb uninstall packagename if you want to be paranoid.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gabe. But when i issue adb install without -r i get INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS msg. I have incremented only versionCode,versionName in the manifest file.Is there anything else i should change in the manifest file to avoid INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS msg.

Comment: Then do an uninstall on it first.  You can even write a quick shell script/batch file that will uninstall and install in 1 command.

Comment: Don't we have any inbuilt support in android to uninstall and install apk in one go, something like "adb update".I thought of the shell script and this would be my last approach.First I want to evaluate inbuilt features with adb. As of now i don't see any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html